# ios Scenekit shadow differs when use custom surface modifier

Tags: ios, shader, scenekit, shadow

I have a simple scene with two planes. First plane with flower texture and shadow is cast on the plane in the background(wall texture).

I have tried to use a surface modifier *SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface* and shadow became totally different. Instead of the flower now it cast the shadow of the plane it self.

Pls see attached images.

1.
  [image]

2.
[image]

My codes
Flower Plane

```
SCNPlane *planeGeometry = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:16.0 height:8.0];
SCNNode *planeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:planeGeometry];
```

code for 1st picture which is ok

```
planeGeometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flowerTexture"];
```

code for 2nd picture which is not ok

```
NSString * surfModifier = ...;

planeGeometry.firstMaterial.shaderModifiers = @{SCNShaderModifierEntryPointSurface : surfModifier};
SCNMaterialProperty* diffuseTexture = [SCNMaterialProperty materialPropertyWithContents:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flowerTexture"]];

[planeGeometry.firstMaterial setValue:diffuseTexture forKey:@"mixTexture"];
```

And the surfModifier shader

```
uniform sampler2D mixTexture;

#pragma transparent
#pragma body

vec4 originalTexture = texture2D(mixTexture, _surface.diffuseTexcoord);
_surface.diffuse = originalTexture;
```

Pls help me to get the 2nd one working

thanks

Comment: In the second case the wall is rendered first, and it includes the shadow caused by the flower plane which at that point has no texture. Then after the wall+shadow is rendered, the flower plane is rendered with your shadermodifier. It does not render the wall and shadow again after that. By default scenekit uses forward shading which adds the shadows during the lighting stage. Normally setting the shadowMode property on your SCNLight to deferred, which causes shadows to be added in a post processing stage, should also solve the shadow shape but it still won’t play nice with the transparency.

Comment: If you would specify the renderingOrder of both plane nodes so the flower is rendered first, the shadow would be correct but not visible through the transparent part of the flower plane (cause then the shadow isn’t rendered on the wall when the transparent portion is determined).

Can you provide some more details about what exactly you are trying to achieve? The simple solution would obviously be to update the diffuse.contents property as you do in code 1 but I’m guessing you want to modify the image in the shader instead of simply using another image from file.

Comment: I think the problem is not in rendering order but simply that the custom shader does not `discard` fragments with an alpha below a certain threshold. Then again I have no idea how much scenekit augments shaders.

Comment: It’s the other way around, a shadermodifier augments the standard scenekit shader. The very point of using them, opposed to a complete custom shader, is keeping basic functionality such as discarding transparent fragments. I’m pretty sure the rendering order is part of the problem here for the reasons I explained above, however changing it isn’t the solution either as it leads to another known problem. It can easily be confirmed by changing the rendering order.

Comment: @Xartec Thanks, changing the light shadowMode deferred not helped the problem. Now everything which i can see through the flowerplane is transparent, except the flower texture. Changing the rendering order has exactly the similar effect. I did it like
flowerNode.renderingOrder = 1;

Comment: The order is ( flowerNode < lightNode < WallNode)

Comment: @LJ Thanks for the hint, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shadermodifier is applied specifically when that flower plane node is rendered. You are essentially post processing the flower plane node which won’t affect the shadows on objects after that.

A solution would be to basically pre-process the flower plane texture, and then assign it to the plane as you do in example 1. So for example, render the flower image to a texture using Metal and you can still modify it with shader code, and then use the result as the texture for the flower plane in Scenekit.

Comment: Thanks @Xartex, I will try to do it.

Comment: That was the solution, thanks. I still have to pass the texture twice. Because I need to create a new texturecoords of the same image, I will ask this question in new thread. Thanks again.